# Error in inserting data in database from datagrid view in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a slight problem don't know what it is

I am trying the following query to insert the data from my datagridview to my database
The problem is that when I am executing the query it gives me the following error

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

However the data is successfully inserted in the database. I tried to find the answers here but to no avail. Somebody please point out the error.

My code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source HERE");
   conn.Open();

   int rn = 0;

   while (rn < dgvmain.Rows.Count)
   {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into mainTab(Token_number,ItemType,Quantity,Amount) values(" + dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[0].Value + ",'" + dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[1].Value + "'," + dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[2].Value + "," + dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[3].Value + ")", conn);

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       rn++;
   }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Can you show me some example i m new to this thanks.

Comment: @ROM The reason for the error is most likely that one of the values is empty. marc's comment is correct though, you should parameterise the query, it will save you a lot of grief.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // put your SqlConnection into a using block
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source HERE"))
        {
            // define query with parameters
            string queryStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.mainTab(Token_number, ItemType, Quantity, Amount) " +
                               "VALUES(@TokenNumber, @ItemType, @Quantity, @Amount)";

            // put your SqlCommand into a using block
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, conn))
            {
                // Add parameter definitions to SqlCommand
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TokenNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemType", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal);

                int rn = 0;

                // now open - as late as possible!
                conn.Open();

                // iterate
                while (rn < dgvmain.Rows.Count)
                {
                    // set parameter values
                    cmd.Parameters["@TokenNumber"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[0].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@ItemType"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[1].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Amount"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[3].Value);

                    // execute INSERT statement
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    rn++;
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice example, although an empty value (which probably caused the problem to begin with) will most likely make `Convert` blow up. Easy to fix, but just so the asker knows there may be value in validating the values before adding them to the database.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: true - I didn't provide all the error handling, just to keep the example simple enough to understand the mechanics of it. But you're absolutely right - this needs to be "hardened" against empty and null values etc. And I've been just *guessing* the data types involved - maybe those are totally different, too...

Answer (score 1):

This is so wrong. Please change it like :

```
       while (rn < dgvmain.Rows.Count)
       {
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into mainTab(Token_number,ItemType,Quantity,Amount) values(@tok,@itm,@qua,@amo)", conn);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tok", dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[0].Value);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itm", dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[1].Value);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qua", dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[2].Value);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amo", dgvmain.Rows[rn].Cells[3].Value);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           rn++;
       }
```

Comment: I have tried it now it gives the error like this :The parameterized query '(@tn nvarchar(4000),@pt nvarchar(4000),@pq nvarchar(4000),@rt nv' expects the parameter '@tn', which was not supplied.

Comment: Please see my answer again.